# How can my containerized Puppeteer talk to my host machine Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, docker, puppeteer

I got Puppeteer working inside a container, which has its own headless Chrome/Chromium, and it will connect to my web app that is running on a different container. Everything works fine.

I'd like the Puppeteer inside the container to run my web app using my host machines Google Chrome (or Chromium, it doesn't matter). I have been searching for something similar but no luck finding documentation on that matter.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Telling puppeteer to connect to the chrome instance on your local machine instead of headless version in the docker container**

1. Run chrome/chromium in debug mode by running `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222` on the terminal. This should give you a Websocket debug url. This should look like this: `ws://host.docker.internal:9222/devtools/browser/d7db2629-0930-4741-a6ca-78ff70863c20`.
2. In your docker dev setup, tell docker to expose port `9222`. This is the debugging port of chrome that we specified. In the yml part of the service running the puppeteer do:

```
service-name:
  build: "..."
  volumes:
    - ....
    - ....
  ports:
    - 3010:3010
    - 9222:9222  <--- Add this
```

And then re-initialize/restart docker containers

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose up
```

3. Now in the code change:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args });
```

to

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
  browserWSEndpoint:
    "ws://host.docker.internal:9222/devtools/browser/d7db2629-0930-4741-a6ca-78ff70863c20"
});
```

*Now the puppeteer should connect to chrome on your local machine and you should see it performing all actions live!*

PS:

or If you dont want to copy the generated url again and again.
You can do

```js
const response = await axios.get(
  "http://host.docker.internal:9222/json/version",
  {
    headers: { Host: "127.0.0.1:9222" }
  }
);
const browserWSEndpoint = response.data.webSocketDebuggerUrl.replace(
  /127.0.0.1/g,
  "host.docker.internal"
);
const browser = await puppeteer.connect({ browserWSEndpoint });
```

This can fetch the debug websocket url from chrome

Comment: This is amazing thank you so much!!
Little note for others (or if you don't mind editing the message): **expose the port on the container is not necessary** since we don't expose anything on that port but rather access the host's chrome instance

Comment: Trying this with the port expose, I get "port already in use" because the port is used by the chrome instance I am running on the host. Without it, I get ECONNREFUSED on connect. Anyone else experiencing anything similar?